# Axios typescript how to define error struct

Tags: typescript, axios

How do you define AxiosError.response type? I have a standard error interface that will be contained within e.response but unable to re-define the type or tell AxiosError my interface.

Thanks all.

[image]

Comment: Try this `... = e.response!`

Comment: It gets rid of the error but what is it doing?

Comment: `var_name!` mean you make sure that `var_name` is defined, the syntax effects when the variable has type like `string | undefined`.

Comment: Amazing !! thank you